# Undo an apt update Command

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running Debian bullseye and wanted to install KeepassXC. I tried running `sudo apt install keepassxc` but it turns out keepassxc is not apart of the bullseye release. I added a line for a sid mirror to /etc/apt/sources.list and then ran `sudo apt update`. After realizing that this was probably a bad idea, I did a keyboard interrupt (Ctrl-C) as the update was running.  It was running for a while at that point and even had requested 2 restarts of programs.  I then commented out the line in the sources.list file and ran `sudo apt update` again, the output of which said there were no updates.  I then ran a `sudo apt autoremove`, which removed 3 packages.

Has my dependency tree been irrevocably messed up?  If I run a `sudo apt upgrade`, would this pull in changes from the sid release?  I don't totally understand the difference between update and upgrade, so this could be a non-issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

Output of `apt policy`:

`Package files: 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status release a=now 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages release v=9.13,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64 origin httpredir.debian.org 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/contrib amd64 Packages release v=9.13,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64 origin httpredir.debian.org 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages release v=9.13,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64 origin httpredir.debian.org 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages release v=9,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64 origin security.debian.org 500 http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages release v=9.13,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64 origin mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu Pinned packages:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m somewhat surprised that `apt update` would request “2 restarts of programs”.

`apt update` retrieves the repository information for all the repositories configured in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. It doesn’t cause any packages to be upgraded, or anything to be restarted or ask to be restarted.

`apt upgrade` upgrades the system’s installed packages so that they match the latest available versions, adjusted according to “pin priorities” if necessary (and the default release, if configured, which is a sort of pin priority).

So `apt update` on its own, after adding entries for Sid, will only retrieve the repository information, it won’t upgrade anything to Sid. Removing the Sid entries and running `apt update` again will result in the Sid information being forgotten (or rather, no longer taken into account). A subsequent `apt upgrade` won’t know about packages (and versions) in Sid.

Your initial problem is surprising, since `keepassxc` [is available in Bullseye](https://packages.debian.org/source/testing/keepassxc) and has been continuously ever since Bullseye has existed.

In summary: if you’ve restored your `/etc/apt/sources.list` configuration to its previous values and run `apt update` since then, nothing will have changed, and you should be able to install `keepassxc` without needing the Sid repositories.

As far as undoing an `apt update` command goes, you can’t ever *fully* undo it unless you have a backup of `/var/lib/apt/lists`, because the information from the repositories which are still configured has been updated. However, *only* the repositories which are still configured are ever taken into account.

Comment: Minor addendum: mixing `sid` and any stable release is *extremely contraindicated* and can lead to minor, major and possibly catastrophic dependency breakdowns. The OP got *lucky* if they only lost three packages.

Comment: @Shadur the OP are running Bullseye, so it’s not that bad; what’s more, nothing suggests that the three removed packages are related to the configuration change — it’s more likely they were already candidates for removal.

Comment: Also, `apt` and `dpkg` are good at what they do, which is ensuring that dependency breakdowns *don’t* happen. Mixing releases does cause problems, but not “dependency breakdowns”.

Comment: @StephenKitt unfortunately, I had run an `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt autoremove` cycle right before this whole exercise, so I'm fairly certain they weren't already candidates for removal, although they could have been.

Comment: @StephenKitt As for the issue of keepassxc not being in bullseye-maybe I had misunderstood. The link provided on keepassxc's site links to sid, and `sudo apt install keepassxc` gives me `Unable to locate package keepassxc`.  Your explanation of update vs upgrade is reassuring, but I don't know why the packages were marked for removal. I also don't know what was going on with the program restart request.  At this point I'm thinking maybe just do a fresh debian install if I start running into issues since I just put debian on this computer. That does seem overkill to me though.

Comment: Do you have the exact quotes for the “restart requests”? Also, could you show the output of `apt policy keepassxc`?

Comment: I don't have the exact quotes, but I will say the screen that displayed looked like that of when you're first installing debian. Output of `apt policy keepassxc`: `N: Unable to locate package keepassxc`-the same output as `sudo apt install keepassxc`.

Comment: As far as I know, `apt update` *never* produces a screen looking like the installer; if you got that, it’s likely you were running `apt upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`, not `apt update`. Regarding `keepassxc`, that result suggests that your repositories are misconfigured for Bullseye; could you edit your question to show the output of `apt policy` (with no additional argument)?

Comment: Well I've decided to just reinstall Debian. I have projects I want to work on and I haven't really done any work so far on this computer.  Sorry @StephenKitt-it seems like you really wanted to resolve this one. Thanks for spending the time working with me to get this resolved.

Comment: Your edit shows why you can’t install `keepassxc`: you’re not running Bullseye, but Stretch, and that doesn’t have `keepassxc`.

Comment: oh...well I've redone the Debian install at this point.  Thanks again for the help.